# Heroku SSL management

Tags: ssl-certificate, certbot, heroku-cli

We are switching to a new third party payment system that requires to provide the SSL certificate of any client interacting with their service (our app in this case) for them to register and approve it.
This means, to avoid payment service interruption on our side, I'll need to create a new certificate and have it trusted by the payment provider while the current one is still valid, then update it before expiration.

The Heroku CLI provides [few methods](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl) to manage certificates: `certs:add`, `certs:remove`, `certs:update`.
I'm not totally clear though how a certificate is "renewed". Do I just need to add the new one and remove the old one? Does `certs:update` do the two operations at once?

Ergo, in my case should I *add* the new certificate while the current one is still valid, then simply *remove* the old certificate once the new one is trusted?
Or do I need to *add* the new one, *update* the current certificate with the new one (again once trusted), and then *remove* the old one?
Or can I just *add* the new and trusted one and whenever the current one expires the new one "kicks in"?

I even tried reading the [Certbot documentations](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#renewing-certificates) (I assume that's what Heroku uses under the hood), but I'm still not entirely sure.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to create a new certificate. Why can't you send them your current certificate?

Comment: if we sent the new certificate once the current - and approved - one has expired, we won't be able to connect to the payment service until the new certificate is registered and approved by them again

Comment: So send the new certificate to them before the old one expires. I still don't see the problem. Send them your current certificate and send them every new certificate you have to create.

Comment: well yes, but my question is about how do I manage the certificate(s), what's the process in practice

Comment: In that case, I don't understand the first paragraph. Did you add it just to distract from your actual problem? Are you asking how to refresh your certificate on Heroku and avoid any downtime?

Comment: @jabaa the "introduction" was meant to give some context on what I need to do and why. I don't understand how the Heroku commands (and more precisely the certificate renewal process/flow) work under the hood. And yes, I'm not sure how to proceed for renewing the certificate avoiding a payment service interruption. 
Of course I ultimately need to find out what't the command sequence I need, but I'd like to understand what's going on when running the commands, more deeply how the certificates (files) are handled.